# Why does Joomla require a Component to be in the Administration Components Menu?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

It seems like this shouldn't be an issue, but I created a generec Ajax component to use for custom Ajax calls. However, I discovered that Joomla requirees a component to be present on the Administrator Components Menu. You even have to specify this in the Component's xml file for this to work properly. Is there anyway to stop this?

thanks!

Comment: There is a possibility to create a custom XML-RPC or even Json plugin, which were made for this purpose. There is no point in creating whole component if it won't be used to manage anything else but clients requests.

Comment: @woodzu How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good explanation in book "Mastering Joomla 1.5 - Extension and Framework Development" by Jams Kennard on how to create XML-RPC extensions like plugins.

Before you start have a look here:

- http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_JSON_output
- http://groups.google.com/group/joomla-dev-cms/msg/c513fe8ef8039083
- and http://docs.joomla.org/Xml-rpc_changes_in_Joomla!_1.6

Also Joomla sources can give a lot of related information

**EDIT:**
ok, let say the only way I can imagine doing this is to remove the link directly from the DB just after your component has been installed (or later):

in your manifest file:

```
<administration>
     <menu>Example Menu Item Text</menu>
     <submenu>
         <menu link="anoption=avalue">Example Submenu Item Text</menu>
     </submenu>
</administration>
<install>
     <sql>
         <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">example.install.sql</file>
     </sql>
</install>
```

in example.install.sql:

```
DELETE FROM jos_menu WHERE (title = "COM_YOUR_COMPONENT" OR title = "com_your_component") AND client_id = 1
```

but to be onest, I've never used it and I don't known if joomla installer will run it in this order:

1. create manu item
2. delete manu item

Comment: it looks like (from the last link you sent me) in Joomla 1.6+ you have make the request part of a component? If so, this means that to make a generic ajax request you have to do this in a custom component?

Comment: This is recommended solution in J1.6+ but you sill can manually add the old xml-rpc library to use it like before (also in plugins)

Comment: hmm, ok, lets say I did a component (or any component for that matter, is there a way to programmatically remove the admin menu item?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to manage the administration menu through advanced admin menu

http://www.theartofjoomla.com/extensions/advanced-administrator-menu.html

You can group your component in a special or existing tab to bring it out of attention

Answer (score 0):

I know in Joomla 1.5 it does'nt require a component to be in that menu? Just don't tell it to put it in the menu! In your component's XML, just make sure the 'administration' block doesn't have a 'menu' entry, like so:

```
<administration>
    <files>
        <filename>blah... </filename>
    </files>
</administration>
```

Adding the `'<menu>'` element to the XML is what adds it to the admin components menu. Creating a post-install SQL file to go back and remove the menu item you've explicitly added seems a bit crazy to me?

Comment: because if you don't have a `<menu>` in your xml, Joomla will put on for your regardless.

Comment: Darn, you're right - I should have tested. What I said worked in Joomla 1.5, but it looks like they changed that behavior in 1.6. 1.6 and 1.7 both add a default menu element.